# Propriedade virtual não é instanciada na lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Quando peguei um código para melhorar a performance eu tinha o seguinte. Um método `GetAll()` esse método populava uma var. Se fazia um `foreach` nessa var e ia atribuindo os devidos valores. Acontece que dentro desse `foreach` havia um comando assim:

```
if (product.PictureId.HasValue)
    item.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;
```

Essa condição é primordial. O problema que esse foreach leva no mínimo uns 4 min para executar e falo de apenas 122 registros(202 no GetAll()). Fiz uma lambda e reduziu no Debug para 17s e no ambiente uns 6s a 10s. Mas o problema está no código acima. Na lambda não consigo trazer isso: `product.Picture.FileName`. Picture é uma propriedade virtual de Product(classe) e Picture é uma classe também. A lambda não a instancia e dá erro de `NullReferenceException`, do tipo:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Falta algum entendimento em Linq/Lambda, para eu concluir esse tópico.
Essa é a lambda completa que fiz e as linhas comentadas são as que estão dando problema. Alem do que postei(Lambda original), fiz várias outras tentativas.

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })

            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)
            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
            {
                ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,

                DolarRate = 0.0m,
                ResellerPriceUSD = 0.0m,
                ResellerPriceBRL = 0.0m,
                BasePriceBRL = 0.0m,
                BasePriceUSD = 0.0m,

                CategoryId = final.Product.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = (c != null ? c.Name : null),
                PictureId = final.Product.PictureId,
                Description = final.Product.Description,
                ShortDescription = final.Product.ShortDescription,
                Name = final.Product.Name,
                NameHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(final.Product.NameHtml) ? final.Product.Name : final.Product.NameHtml,
                PartNumber = final.Product.PartNumber,
                Hidden = final.Product.Hidden,
                Order = final.Product.Order,
                HaveMaximumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage,
                MaximumPercentage = final.Product.MaximumPercentage,
                HaveMinimumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage,
                MinimumPercentage = final.Product.MinimumPercentage,
                AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
                AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
                StandardMarkup = final.Product.StandardMarkup,
                DistributionCenterErpId = final.Product.DistributionCenterErpId,
                PictureFilename = final.Product.Picture.FileName

            }).ToList();

            qry.ForEach(q =>
            {
                var product = new Product();

                product.CategoryId = q.CategoryId;
                product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;
                product.HaveMaximumPercentage = q.HaveMaximumPercentage;
                product.HaveMinimumPercentage = q.HaveMinimumPercentage;
                product.Hidden = q.Hidden;
                product.ChildrenCategoryId = q.ChildrenCategoryId;
                product.Description = q.Description;
                product.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId;
                product.MaximumPercentage = q.MaximumPercentage;
                product.MinimumPercentage = q.MinimumPercentage;
                product.Name = q.Name;
                product.NameHtml = q.NameHtml;
                product.Order = q.Order;
                product.PartNumber = q.PartNumber;
                product.PictureId = q.PictureId;
                product.ShortDescription = q.ShortDescription;
                product.StandardMarkup = q.StandardMarkup;

                var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);
                q.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);

                //if (product.PictureId.HasValue)
                //    q.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;

                var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

                if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                    q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                q.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                q.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;

            });

            return qry;
```

Comment: Quando eu dou um new Product(), já perco as referências a todas as propriedades virtuais em Product, correto? Fora do `ForEach()` lambda, eu realmente não sei onde atribuir os valores que estão dentro do if.

Comment: teria como postar um projecto apenas com o essencial, reproduzindo o problema, para poder testar deste lado?

Comment: Quando eu faço `var product = new Product()` estou matando o Lazy loading e isso deixa Picture de fora, correto? E como eu faço ou mantenho o Lazy loading?

Answer (score 1):

Observando seu código vejo que a variável `product` está recebendo uma nova instância `var product = new Product()` mas em momento algum foi atribuído um valor para `product.Picture` logo ela está nula (a menos que você tenha atribuído valor no construtor vazio da classe `Product`), nesse caso se você acessar qualquer propriedade de Picture receberá a exception: "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto".
Em caso de ter ativado o `LazyLoading` dentro do linq você consegue carregar as propriedades virtuais de forma automática, no seu caso o código que acabei de citar se encontra fora da geração da consulta pois ela terminou quando você realizou a 'Execução imediata' através do `ToList()`.

Comment: Anderson Paiva, um `.Include(pic => pic.Product.Picture` pode resolver? Esse include  aqui: ` var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .Include(pic => pic.Product.Picture)
            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)`

Comment: Sua classe CatalogItemResponse precisa ter uma propriedade para receber Picture daí você atribui dentro do SelectMany
o valor 'Picture = final.Product.Picture' com isso você poderia descomentar seu código no ForEach pois se houver valor em Picture será preenchido
(se você não tiver ligado o LazyLoading use o include que você mesmo citou acima)

Comment: Uma coisa. Na CatalogItemResponse eu tenho isso: `PictureFilename = final.Product.Picture.FileName`, isso deveria resolver, mas não e o if continua dando pau

Comment: isso não resolveria pois `PictureFileName` deve ser uma propriedade do tipo string, e `final.Product.Picture.FileName` também, o erro que o código está gerando é no acesso a um objeto não instanciado

Comment: olhando seu código novamente percebi que ao invés de `q.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;` você poderia usar `q.PictureFilename = product.PictureFileName;`

Comment: Eu não tenho product.PictureFileName, mas entendi criar uma nova propriedade que receba Picture, acho

Comment: Só consigo atribuir dessa forma: `public virtual Product.Picture Picture { get; set; }`, mas acho que não é isso

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91091/discussion-between-anderson-paiva-and-pnet).